# What is the right way to spell Ukrainian capital Kyiv or Kiev?

Tags: spelling

Is there a correct way to spell it or are both correct? Are there any formal references to the correct spelling?

Comment: This question is not about the Ukrainian language.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov I've found a way! Ask about pronunciation, not about spelling! And tell everyone you want to know how to spell it right, that's why you need to know, what is the right way to pronounce it in Ukrainian!

Answer (score 6):

Well, the Ukrainians (probably, majority of those who care) prefer to see that city name spelled as "**Kyiv**" in Latin script. (There were even [some official tries](http://www.uazone.net/Kiev_Kyiv.html) (also see [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20050215181512/http://www.rada.gov.ua/translit) and [this](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0957-14/page2)) to convince others to call us in that way.)

But, still, that issue is outside of the scope of the Ukrainian language and of the sphere of influence of Ukrainians. **We can only ask** others to call our city in this way; not give any "orders" to other countries/nations/governments/peoples.

Comment: And in Chinese "Kyiv" is 基輔 Jīfǔ (_Цзіфу_) and we really cannot do anything about it. ))

Comment: There is official document about this: http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z0957-14/page2